# Why does datetime('now') return 2 hours before real time in SQLite?

Tags: android, sqlite, datetime, utc

I need that every time I make a change to a certain record from a table in SQLite, in the column lastChangedDate to set the time from France. Here is the structure of my table :

```
CREATE TABLE name(
    id VARCHAR(36) PRIMARY KEY
    , pos_report_id VARCHAR(36)
    , path_name VARCHAR(64)
    , photo_name VARCHAR(64)
    , from_scratch INTEGER DEFAULT 0
    , lastChangedDate DATETIME DEFAULT (DATETIME('now', 'utc', '1 hours'))
)
```

I see that `DATETIME('now')` returns 2 hours before my real time and `DATETIME('now', 'utc', '1 hours')` returns with 3 hours before my time. Why is happening this? I need the application to work in more countries, so I cannot use `localtime`.

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 5):

I have the same problem (using sqlite on Raspbarry Pi). 'utc' obviously only calcultes the difference according to location and timezone. I got it running like this:

```
select datetime(datetime('now', 'localtime'), 'utc');
```

Also check out the other variation of my VIEW [NOW] for sensor logging purpose.

```
CREATE VIEW [NOW] AS 
SELECT datetime('now', 'localtime') as LOCAL,
datetime(datetime('now', 'localtime'),'utc') as UTC, 
substr(datetime('now', 'localtime'),1,17)||'00' as TimeSlot_1min, 
substr(datetime('now', 'localtime'),1,15)||'0:00' as TimeSlot_10min, 
substr(datetime('now', 'localtime'),1,14)||'00:00' as TimeSlot_1h;
```

Answer (score 2):

try datetime('now','localtime')  instead of DATETIME('now', 'utc', '1 hours') 
Ok dont use default time for lastChangedDate

```
CREATE TABLE name(
    id VARCHAR(36) PRIMARY KEY
    , pos_report_id VARCHAR(36)
    , path_name VARCHAR(64)
    , photo_name VARCHAR(64)
    , from_scratch INTEGER DEFAULT 0
    , lastChangedDate DATETIME)
)
```

then when you want to add record to table, you can calculate the time in France and add this value to your database

```
//Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
//Log.v("hata",String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.HOUR)));

Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

// It is local time
Log.v("time",String.valueOf(c.getTime()));

TimeZone z = c.getTimeZone();       
int offset = z.getRawOffset();

if(z.inDaylightTime(new Date())){
    offset = offset + z.getDSTSavings();
}

// france is GMT2 
int offsetHrs = offset / 1000 / 60 / 60;
int offsetMins = offset / 1000 / 60 % 60;

// Offsets
Log.v("time",String.valueOf(offsetHrs));
Log.v("time",String.valueOf(offsetMins));

c.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, (-offsetHrs));
c.add(Calendar.MINUTE, (-offsetMins));

// FRANCE time
Log.v("time",String.valueOf(c.getTime()));
```

Comment: I wrote that I need the application to work in many countries. If I am in Africa and my hour is 4:00, in France can be 7:00. I need to know which is the hour in France from any country.

Comment: datetime('now','localtime') works for my case, thanks :)